# How to add CSS attributes to background-size support in wordpress Custom Background

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to add support for CSS3 attributes background-size, background-clip and background-origin, in the custom backgrounds. To do so, I've modified the fully-background-manager plugin (a very simple plugin that sets custom backgrounds per page), to set those attributes.

They seem to be set and stored correctly in the admin interface, but when generating the style tag that sets them, the new values are ignored; the only supported properties seem to be the ones mentioned in http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Backgrounds

Custom background are generated by Wordpress itself, not the theme. I know that the theme must enable it use by declaring itself compatible and setting defaults with

```html
add_theme_support( 'custom-background', $defaults );
and Wordpress will generate the custom-background css code

<style type="text/css" id="custom-background-css">
body.custom-background { background-color: #bdd96e; }
</style>
```

And the plugin itself seems to use

```html
add_filter( 'theme_mod_background_image', array( $this, 'fbm_background_image' ), 25 );
```

to set/override the default css attributes, like 'theme_mod_background_image', but it only prints the css of the supported/overriden variables. In other words, Wordpress does not know theme_mod_background_size, so it cannot override it to print it.

Is there a way to add those attributes to Wordpress itself? I've reading the code of admin/custom-background.php, but I've failed to see any reference to the supported attribute list. Are they in some hidden include? In the the database itself? If I were to set them, would wordpress generate the CSS anyway?

I hope I have explained it properly. I've not found anything about it. The majority of plug-ins set those values in javascript with jQuery instead of using the proper CSS attributes. If not, a tutorial about the internal workings of the lastest version of wordpress itself could be useful as a clue to investigate.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use the callback parameter `wp-head-callback` with a custom function:

```
add_theme_support( 'custom-background', array( 'wp-head-callback'=> 'my_custom_background_cb' ) );
```

You could replace the entire default `_custom_background_cb` callback function copying and modifying it, but I don't like to duplicate code if is not necessary, so I would do something like this:

```
function my_custom_background_cb() {
    ob_start();
    _custom_background_cb();
    $buffer = ob_get_clean();

    $my_style = "
        background-size: 80px 60px;
        background-clip: border-box;
        background-origin: content-box;
    ";

    echo str_replace('</', $my_style.'</', $buffer);
}
```

I get the original code from `_custom_background_cb` and then I can add my style code before echoing.

Obviously you need to put in `$my_style` your attributes data.

Answer (score 1):

I was reading [here](https://make.wordpress.org/themes/2012/04/06/updating-custom-backgrounds-and-custom-headers-for-wordpress-3-4/), and it seems to be as easy as reference your custom function with the css in it, to the parameter that is for the admin head callback...

```
<?php
 add_theme_support( 'custom-background', array('wp-head-callback' => custom_function));

    function custom_function() {
        echo '<style>';
        //your custom css
        echo '</style>';
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.let me elaborate my problem. I was using wordprss plugin fully background manager for setting background image for pages/posts. but the image was not alligned properly so i need to add a css snippet for working properly. css should be added to the tag body.custom-background.As you said I added add_theme_support( 'custom-background', array( 'wp-head-callback'=> 'my_custom_background_cb' ));
instead of add_theme_support( 'custom-background');
in the plugin fbm.php and  defined the function .but now the image is not displaying in the page.please help me

Comment: And here is my function defined :function my_custom_background_cb() {
    ob_start();
    _custom_background_cb();
    $buffer = ob_get_clean();

    $my_style = 'body.custom-background {
background-attachment: fixed;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
';


    echo str_replace('</', $my_style.'</', $buffer);
}

Comment: Thanks.one more doubt how to add css inside  echo '<style>';
        //your custom css
        echo '</style>';   would you please tell  the syntax for css inside php

Comment: @JohnSimon I think you made some confusion commenting on this answer referring the code of my previous answer. The problem with this answer is that it removes the native Wordpress functionality of choosing a custom background (you replace it totally with your code), while mine mantains it (you just add your css rules).

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the admin head callback function to add the other CSS?

Comment: please tell me how and where to add css with the admin head callback??                            is it like adding  add_theme_support( 'custom-background',$style);
and adding css style as arguments with the $style array??

Comment: I'm not really sure I'd never done it. I only done it for the theme head, but I think its quiet the same... 

I usually add a custom function with my css like '<style> custom css </style>'   
and then add the function to the wp_head
add_action( 'wp_head', 'custom_function' );